# hierarchical forecast (hts package) R uneven groups and custom forecast

Tags: r, forecasting

I am going through the read me for the hts package. I am interested in trying out the custom forecast section, which requires looping through each series with a specified forecast function. The example provided shows even number of groups. I would like to know how can I run custom forecasts with uneven number of groups, and then recombining them into a gts object.

```
bts <- ts(5 + matrix(sort(rnorm(500)), ncol=5, nrow=100))
y <- hts(bts, nodes=list(2, c(3, 2)))

allts_y <- aggts(y)
allf <- matrix(allts_y, nrow=100, ncol=ncol(allts_y))

for(i in 1:ncol(allts_y))
  allf[,i] <- forecast(auto.arima(allts_y[,i]), h=10)$mean
allf <- ts(allf, start=1)

# below code is where I run into a hang-up
g <- matrix(c(rep(2, 5), rep(3, 5), rep(1:5, 2)), nrow = 2, byrow = T)
y.f <- combinef(allf, groups = g)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your group structure `g` does not match the hierarchical structure specified  by the `nodes` argument in `hts()`. Replace the last line by

```
y.f <- combinef(allf, nodes=y$nodes)
```

Comment: Thank you, Dr. Hyndman. I see now that the differences between the two data objects and how I was trying to fit a square peg into a round hole. I'll be sure to distinguish groups and nodes in the future.